Plotting planet position as a function of time
I've been trying to make a simulation of planets and asteroids moving around the sun, and I found this link:
How do I plot a planet's orbit as a function of time on an already plotted ellipse?
I decided to study and try out the code from the linked question. But it seems like I am either using it incorrectly or the code is wrong, because when I plot the orbits for Mars, Earth, Jupiter, Mercury, and Venus, they don't seem to line up with online simulations from NASA, such as this one:
https://eyes.nasa.gov/apps/solar-system/#/home
Current positions, according to a NASA simulation:

Current positions, according to my plot:

Code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Circle

# Set axes aspect to equal as orbits are almost circular; hence square is needed
ax = plt.figure(0).add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

# Setting the title, axis labels, axis values and introducing a grid underlay
# Variable used so title can indicate user inputed date
plt.title('Inner Planetary Orbits at[user input date]')
plt.ylabel('x10^6 km')
plt.xlabel('x10^6 km')
ax.set_xlim(-300, 300)
ax.set_ylim(-300, 300)
plt.grid()

# Creating the point to represent the sun at the origin (not to scale), 
ax.scatter(0,0,s=200,color='y')
plt.annotate('Sun', xy=(0,-30))

# Implementing ellipse equations to generate the values needed to plot an ellipse
# Using only the planet's min (m) and max (M) distances from the sun
# Equations return '2a' (the ellipses width) and '2b' (the ellipses height)
def OrbitLength(M, m):
    a=(M+m)/2
    c=a-m
    e=c/a
    b=a*(1-e**2)**0.5
    print(a)
    print(b)
    return 2*a, 2*b

# This function uses the returned 2a and 2b for the ellipse function's variables
# Also generating the orbit offset (putting the sun at a focal point) using M and m
def PlanetOrbit(Name, M, m):
    w, h = OrbitLength(M, m)
    Xoffset= ((M+m)/2)-m
    Name = Ellipse(xy=((Xoffset),0), width=w, height=h, angle=0, linewidth=1, fill=False)
    ax.add_artist(Name)

    
    
from math import *

EPSILON = 1e-12
def solve_bisection(fn, xmin,xmax,epsilon = EPSILON):
  while True:
      xmid = (xmin + xmax) * 0.5
      if (xmax-xmin < epsilon):
        return xmid
      fn_mid = fn(xmid)
      fn_min = fn(xmin)
      if fn_min*fn_mid < 0:
          xmax = xmid
      else:
          xmin = xmid
    
'''
Found something similar at this gamedev question:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11116/kepler-orbit-get-position-on-the-orbit-over-time?newreg=e895c2a71651407d8e18915c38024d50

Equations taken from:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Position_as_a_function_of_time
'''
def SolveOrbit(rmax, rmin, t):
  # calculation precision
  epsilon = EPSILON
  # mass of the sun [kg]
  Msun = 1.9891e30
  # Newton's gravitational constant [N*m**2/kg**2]
  G = 6.6740831e-11
  # standard gravitational parameter
  mu = G*Msun
  # eccentricity
  eps = (rmax - rmin) / (rmax + rmin)
  # semi-latus rectum
  p = rmin * (1 + eps)
  # semi/half major axis
  a = p / (1 - eps**2)
  # period
  P = sqrt(a**3 / mu)
  # mean anomaly
  M = (t / P) % (2*pi)
  # eccentric anomaly
  def fn_E(E):
    return M - (E-eps*sin(E))
  E = solve_bisection(fn_E, 0, 2*pi)
  # true anomaly
  # TODO: what if E == pi?
  theta = 2*atan(sqrt((((1+eps)*tan(E/2)**2)/(1-eps))))
  # if we are at the second half of the orbit
  if (E > pi):
    theta = 2*pi - theta
  # heliocentric distance
  r = a * (1 - eps * cos(E))
  return theta, r

def DrawPlanet(name, rmax, rmin, t):
  SCALE = 1e9
  theta, r = SolveOrbit(rmax * SCALE, rmin * SCALE, t)
  x = -r * cos(theta) / SCALE
  y = r * sin(theta) / SCALE
  planet = Circle((x, y), 8)
  ax.add_artist(planet)
    
# These are the arguments taken from hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solar/soldata2.html
# They are the planet names, max and min distances, and their longitudinal angle
#Also included is Halley's Comet, used to show different scale  and eccentricity
PlanetOrbit('Mercury', 69.8, 46.0)
PlanetOrbit('Jupiter', 741, 817)
PlanetOrbit('Venus', 108.9, 107.5)
PlanetOrbit('Earth', 152.1, 147.1)
PlanetOrbit('Mars', 249.1, 206.7)


# t = time since perihelion in seconds
DrawPlanet('Earth', 152.1, 147.1, 206*60*60*24)
DrawPlanet('Mars', 249.1, 206.7, 77*60*60*24) 
DrawPlanet('Mercury', 69.8, 46.0, 43*60*60*24)
DrawPlanet('Jupiter', 741, 817, 552*60*60*24)
DrawPlanet('Venus', 108.9, 107.5, 16*60*60*24)  

print(60*60*24*365)
  
plt.show()

The two images don't seem to line up obviously, so I tried many things, such as: using only earth's perihelion time, rewriting the SolveOrbit function, and using the JPL HORIZONS API to find perihelion time in case it is wrong, which I was not able to find.
I am starting to think the issue is in the times "t" that I am inputting and not the program, as I got them from this website:
https://in-the-sky.org/news.php?id=20210612_11_100
And perhaps it's inaccurate, but I'm unsure where else to find a perihelion time.

The comments in your code bear little resemblance to the code itself. Function PlanetOrbit() does NOT have an argument for longitudinal angle: as far as I can see the axes of the ellipses will all align with the same coordinate axes. (And there’s no Halley’s Comet.) For those of us unfamiliar with the websites that you linked to it is not obvious how you extracted the data from them. You might also want to define a variable “day” with the value 606024, rather than keep repeating the same calculation. Kepler’s second law will give you position on an orbit.

time since perihelion in seconds doesn't make sense, perihelions are not in sync. you need to have a time frame. libraries like skyfield use nasa's jpl ephemerides with defined time frames, see JPL Planetary and Lunar Ephemerides
